# Create std::u8string from std::string/char const* when the latter is already in utf-8

Tags: c++, string, char8-t

I'm in the process of upgrading my code base to C++20 and would like to make use of `std::u8string`/`char8_t`. I'm using a 3rd-party library that takes and returns UTF-8 strings in its API, however it hasn't been updated to C++20 yet and thus takes and returns the UTF-8 strings as regular `std::string`s instead of `std::u8string`s.

Converting `std::u8string` to `std::string` is pretty straight-forward, as the `u8string`s buffer may be accessed through a `char*` pointer, so

```
std::u8string u8s = get_data();
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(u8s.data()), u8s.size());
```

is valid code. However, as far as I'm aware `char8_t` does not have the aliasing exemption that `std::byte` and `char` have, thus

```
std::string s = get_data();
std::u8string u8s{reinterpret_cast<char8_t const*>(s.data()), s.size());
```

is not valid.

I've resorted to

```
std::string s = get_data();
std::u8string u8s(s.size(), u8'\0');
std::memcpy(u8s.data(), s.data(), s.size());
```

for now, but that seems unnecessarily inefficient given that this first initializes the memory to all zeroes before writing the actual data into it.

Is there a way to avoid the initialization to all zeroes or another way to convert between `std::string` and `std::u8string` altogether?

Comment: `u8string u8s(s.begin(), s.end());` maybe. I'm assuming there's no problem converting `char` to `char8_t` but I'm not familiar with `char8_t`.

Comment: `Converting std::u8string to std::string is pretty straight-forward,` only if text inside `std::string` also uses `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: @MarekR Sure, but that was the assumption I explicitly stated before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u8string u8s(s.begin(), s.end())` should work just fine. You don't need the cast. The constructor is templated, and `char` implicitly converts to `char8_t`.

The underlying type of `char8_t` being `unsigned char` is not a problem even if `char` is a signed type.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I assumed that `char8_t` and `char` aren't implicitly convertible to one-another just because the pointers `char8_t*` and `char*` aren't...